# HTML/CSS stacking underline needed

Tags: html, css

For scientific purpose we need to style the text similar to underline, but it must be color and even more important: stacking. Basically the same word could be underlined with the red straight line and with the green wavy underline at the same time, for instance. In our old editor for Windows we had up to five levels of six different decorations, but now for browser mere two would be enough. Is there any way to achieve that?

So we need at least three various styles of underline (for example straight line, dotted, wavy, but it does not matter, this could be any sort of decorations), and each line must be it's own color, and draw at least two under the same word.

We already use text color, background color, and font, so that is not an option.

Comment: You could do this with nested elements, possibly sprites, etc. What have you tried?

Comment: Or a whole bunch of cleverly constructed `box-shadow` properties.

Comment: Perhaps you could fake it with a `border-bottom: ` ?? :)

Answer (score 2):

This solution will work if you are able to make use of the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`.

You can take any text that will require an underline and wrap it in a `<span>` tag. Then you can style the `<span>` and it's `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Make sure the `<span>` elements `position` is set to `relative`. This will allow you to position the pseudo elements relative to the span and not some element higher up in the DOM.

**EDIT:**

Any word/sentence you would like to underline should be wrapped in a `<span></span>` tag and given the class of **underline**; As well as any of the underline style classes (`.info, .alert, .warning`).

we can update the snippet below from:

```
<span class="alert info warning underline">dolor sit amet,consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
```

to:

```
<span class="alert info underline">dolor sit amet, <span class="warning underline">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit.</span>
```

As you can see we wrap the word consectetur in `<span class="underline warning"></span>` allowing it to inherit the parent spans `.info` and `.alert` underlines all while adding it's own `.warning` underline to the mix.

```css
p{
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.underline{
    position: relative;
}
.alert:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102%;
    left: 0;
}
.info:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: dashed 1px blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 135%;
    left: 0;
}
.warning{
    border-bottom: dotted 1px green;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum <span class="alert info underline">dolor sit amet, <span class="warning underline">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit.</span> Eveniet fugit ducimus debitis eos quos maxime labore voluptatem qui iusto consequuntur quod mollitia deleniti quia possimus dicta nihil autem blanditiis quidem!</p>
```

Comment: This looks impressive, but I cannot understand it at all! How do you modify it to have the sentence alert+info and only one word inside the sentence to be also warning+underline?